# Мультирегиональность по URL в CMS BITRIX в рамках одного домена. Нужна помощь

Tags: битрикс

День добрый.
Такой вопрос, есть задача сделать мультирегиональность для вывода названия города в товарном каталоге, но, не через доменные имена, аля moscow.site.ru, spb.site.ru, а через URL вида: /msk/catalog/, /spb/catalog/
Сейчас, делаю это через:

1. копирование самой папки каталога, в нужные подпапки /msk/, /spb/
2. добавляю файл .section.php с кодом $arDirProperties = Array("city" =>"Москва") в данные папки.
3. копирования правила обработки компонента catalog в файле urlrewrite.php.
   Все, вроде бы водится корректно, но, подозреваю, что это какой-то тупиковый путь развития, ибо, если городов будет больше, чем два, то, копировать все это каждый раз, будет проблемно.
   Подскажите пожалуйста, может какие-нибудь примеры кода по ссылке, где приведенная выше задача, решилась более гуманным образом?
   Через urlrewrite обработка адресов каталога, или типа того?
   Может за какую-нибудь адекватную цену кто возьмется сделать (500-1000 р)? черканите тогда, это тоже все обсуждается.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Путь тупиковый, однозначно.

Лучший вариант:

1. Завести отдельный инфоблок с городами.
2. В самом каталоге сделать привязку товаров к элементам инфоблока.
3. Оставить один файл, который будет обрабатывать все города.
4. Завернуть через urlrewrite.php все запросы на него
5. В этом файле выбирать название города по коду, менять заголовок и настраивать фильтр для каталога.